# Spfx extension Clear cache or hard refresh

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, spfx-extensions, react, typescript

I have four different extensions with different languages with texts on it, I use dropdown on top placeholder to switch between different sites. However, when I switch from English to Polish I still see the English Text in Polish site.

I was wondering how to clear cache when selecting the item from dropdown or make a hard refresh

Answer (score 0):

You can have the browser reload by using `window.location.reload()`.

Clearing the cache, however, is only possible in Firefox where `window.location.reload(true)` is supported.

More Details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

---

Additionally, there is increasing support for the [Clear-Site-Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data) header that might be worth investigating. Not sure it's applicable in this case, however.

Comment: Even though when I hit reload manually the extension remains the same, I mean When switching from English to Polish in Polish still shows english text. But after sometime it loads the text of polish.